# How to generate the following statistic from a table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named `incident_summary` that structure and data as following:

`month,system_id,s_count`

`202104,1,50`

`202104,2,6`

`202105,1,14`

`202105,2,4`

`202106,1,1`

`202106,2,1`

I would like to generate the following statistic:

`s_count_on_202106,s_count_before_202106`

`2,74`

where

`s_count_on_202106` is sum of `s_count` value on 202106

`s_count_before_202106` is sum of `s_count` value before 202106

I have tried the following SQL:

```
select  
  sum(case when month<202106 then s_count else 0 end)
  sum(case when month=202106 then s_count else 0 end)
from incident_summary
group by month
```

However, it does not work, would you help to me to solve the problem?

Comment: "It does not work". How does that mean? Is there any error message?

Comment: You don't need `group by month`. Remove that and run the query again. You should be able to get the result you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following Query.
May be it helps you.

```
SELECT
    t1.s_count_on_202106,
    t2.s_count_before_202106
FROM
(
    SELECT
        sum(s_count) AS s_count_on_202106
    FROM
        incident_summary
    WHERE
        month = 202106
) AS t1,
(
    SELECT
        sum(s_count) AS s_count_before_202106
    FROM
        incident_summary
    WHERE
        month < 202106
) AS t2
```

Answer (score 0):

Sum again on your result set.

```
SELECT SUM(s_count_before_202106)s_count_before_202106,  SUM(s_count_on_202106)s_count_on_202106
FROM
(
    select  
      sum(case when month<202106 then s_count else 0 end)s_count_before_202106 ,
      sum(case when month=202106 then s_count else 0 end)s_count_on_202106
    from incident_summary
    group by month
)T;
```